/run/user/$UID directory not created after "su - user" while $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is properly defined
Context
We are working on RHEL 8.5 with an applicative user 'userpodman' created specially for executing podman commands.
This user was created with the following set of commands:
[root@machine ~]$ adduser userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ usermod --add-subuids 10000-75535 userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ usermod --add-subgids 10000-75535 userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ loginctl enable-linger userpodman@

Then in order to perform podman commands we always login as that user using:
[root@machine ~]$ su - userpodman
[userpodman@machine ~]$ podman ps
(expected command output here)

Podman version:
[userpodman@machine ~]$ podman version
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.2.0
API Version:  4.2.0
Go Version:   go1.18.4
Built:        Wed Nov  9 14:16:58 2022
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Problem
For a while this was working as intended and we were able to execute podman commands through this user without issue, but at some point after letting the host machine run for a while, we started experiencing the following error on any podman command:
[userpodman@machine ~]$ podman ps
ERRO[0000] stat /run/user/1001: no such file or directory

After a quick check it appears that this folder was indeed removed without any action on our side:
[root@machine ~]$ ll /run/user
total 0

After looking for some online documentation about this issue we came across issues talking about the XDG_RUNTIME_DIR that could potentially be badly defined, but according to the following verification they do indeed have the expected value:
[userpodman@machine ~]$ id
uid=1001(userpodman) gid=1001(userpodman) groupes=1001(userpodman)
[userpodman@machine ~]$ echo "$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR"
/run/user/1001

Same goes for the podman config file in /home/userpodman/.config/containers/storage.conf (without comments or empty sections):
[storage]
driver = "overlay"
runroot = "/run/user/1001"
graphroot = "/opt/project_dir/containers/storage"

[storage.options]
additionalimagestores = [
]

[storage.options.overlay]
mountopt = "nodev,metacopy=on"

Attempted Solutions
We tried deleting and recreating the user with following set of commands provided by one of our internal FAQ:
[root@machine ~]$ rm -rf /home/userpodman/.config
[root@machine ~]$ rm -rf /opt/project_dir
[root@machine ~]$ killall -u userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ userdel -r -f userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ systemctl restart centrifyda
[root@machine ~]$ mkdir -p /var/lib/systemd/linger
[root@machine ~]$ touch /var/lib/systemd/linger/userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ adduser userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ usermod --add-subuids 10000-75535 userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ usermod --add-subgids 10000-75535 userpodman
[root@machine ~]$ loginctl enable-linger userpodman@

But then a different error started to occur:
[userpodman@machine ~]$ podman ps
Error: mkdir /run/user/1001: permission denied

We also attempted to reboot the device but it simply went back to the first error above.
Workaround
Currently we found only one way to solve this temporarily by creating manually the expected folder and giving it the proper ownership:
[root@machine ~]$ mkdir /run/user/1001
[root@machine ~]$ chown userpodman:userpodman /run/user/1001

Sadly this does not survive a reboot or another random delete of that directory by the system...
So we would prefer to have a clearer understanding of why is this directory even deleted, and how to ensure it is recreated as expected whenever we login as userpodman.
Request
I have crossed many tickets with similar issues that seemed promising, but in the end none of them were exactly matching our case (most of them were either using a bad user to execute the commands or had an their XDG_RUNTIME_DIR variable either empty or filled with a bad path) and none of the solutions suggested for them had any effect on our machine...
Here is a quick list of the tickets that I have already consulted without finding a proper answer:

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/7020802
Why is the $XDG_RUNTIME_DIR (/run/user/$UID) directory not created after "su - user"?
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/13338
https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/5094

Any insight on this problem or advice on how to investigate it further would be appreciated.
Progress
As suggested by Erik Sjölund we tried to login with machinectl shell userpodman@ instead of su - userpodman but still experienced the same error.
We also managed to poinpoint when the folder gets deleted after we recreate it manually: it is whenever we execute the following command:
[root@machine ~]$ loginctl enable-linger userpodman@

After further investigation in this direction it appears the "linger" state of userpodman is somehow broken...
We can see the user listed in /var/lib/systemd/linger, but it does not appear in the list of lingering users:
[root@machine ~]# loginctl list-users
No users.

Attempting to get more information on this user from loginctl also result into an error:
[root@machine ~]# loginctl show-user userpodman | grep Linger
Failed to get user: User ID 1001 is not logged in or lingering

Note that right after a reboot, the loginctl list-users does show userpodman as a result, but as soon as we login/logout as this user, we lose it.

You can at least check whether it is gone because user-runtime-dir@1001.service has been stopped somehow.

This service say it is inactive and exited with status code zero last time it was used when I request its status after connecting with the userpodman account.

I believe this command has incorrect syntax: loginctl enable-linger userpodman@   Try removing the @

Good point, I believed it was part of the command syntax the same way you can use it in "machinectl shell", but apparently it is not... I tried removing it but it did not lead to any improvement on the issue encountered sadly.

Weirdly enough it is indeed working with that syntax on all of our other machines even if it appears to be invalid syntax, only one of our machines experiences the issue described in this ticket.

Use
sudo machinectl shell userpodman@

The same command can also be written:
sudo machinectl shell --uid=userpodman

See this blog as to why not use su when running rootless podman:
Why can't I run rootless Podman containers when I log into a user via sudo or su? https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/sudo-rootless-podman
Here is an example of the difference between su and machinectl
Add new user
root@localhost:/# useradd test

test su
root@localhost:/# su - test
test@localhost:~$ env | grep XDG
test@localhost:~$ env | grep DBUS
test@localhost:~$ exit
logout

test machinectl
root@localhost:~ # machinectl shell test@
Connected to the local host. Press ^] three times within 1s to exit session.
test@localhost:~$ env | grep XDG
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
XDG_SESSION_ID=50
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1003
test@localhost:~$ env | grep DBUS
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1003/bus
test@localhost:~$ 


I had to install the systemd-container package but I now have access to machinectl, I will try this suggestion next time I encounter the issue (I used the workaround presented above right after posting this message so it is not currently broken).

Well I just encountered the issue again and tried to login with machinectl shell userpodman@ which let me login, sadly I am still getting the exact same error I used to get with su - userpodman... I checked the env variables as well and the only one defined for me is XDG_RUNTIME_DIR, the others are not there, could this be part of the issue?
